# get_the_terms - but only show 4 Posts

Tags: wp-query, terms

I am using this code to load related posts with a custom taxonomy term slug:

```
<?php
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'topics', 'string');
$do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;

if(!empty($terms)){
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        query_posts( array(
        'topics' => $term->slug,
        'showposts' => 4,
        'caller_get_posts' => 1,
        'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate ) );
        if(have_posts()){
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
```

But I always get more than 4 posts. How can I really set this query to just 4 posts?

Thanks!

AD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify number of posts to retrieve. 'showposts' is how many to show on page, and is deprecated (use 'posts_per_page' instead)

```
'showposts' => 4,
'numberposts' => 4,
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks!

This works:

```
<?php
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'topics', 'string');
$do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;

if(!empty($terms)){
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        query_posts( array(
        'topics' => $term->slug,
        'numberposts' => 4,
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'caller_get_posts' => 1,
        'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate ) );
        if(have_posts()){
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
```